# How do I create a PDO query with a LIKE statement?

Tags: php, html

Here's my attempt at it:

```
if(isset($_POST['recherche'])){
    $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM produits WHERE Nom_produit LIKE ?');
    $req->execute(array('Nom_produit' => $_POST['recherche']));
    if($resultat = $req->fetch()){
    $url = $resultat['ref_produit'].'.php';
    header("location: $url ");}
    else { ?>
    <script>alert('Produit Non Trouvé');</script>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

I need some help !! please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enclose the value in %

So Change this line:

```
$req->execute(array('Nom_produit' => $_POST['recherche']));
```

to

```
$req->execute(array('%' . $_POST['recherche'] . '%'));
```

That should work

Comment: Haha it needed a downvote as your first initial answer was incorrect, it was only after you edited your answer after either seeing mine, or properly researching the subject that you decided to edit your answer into one that was correct.

Comment: Actually, the first revision of this post had the `%` in place. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16760353/1

Answer (score 2):

The like parameter needs to be enclosed in `%`.

Like below,

```
$req->execute(array('%' . $_POST['recherche'] . '%'));
```